# What is the infinite product of (primes^2+1)/(primes^2-1)?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, infinite-product

I have shown that the infinite product $$\prod_{p \in \mathcal{P}}\frac{p^2+1}{p^2-1}$$ is equal to $\frac{5}{2}$ (pretty remarkable!). I have checked this numerically with Wolfram Alpha for up to $500000$ primes and it seems true.

I was wondering if this result is recorded anywhere?

Also if true, does this mean that there aren't infinitely many primes of form $p^2+1$?

Comment: Care to share with us the proof? Just asking.

Comment: Some [links at MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/228830/how-do-i-show-that-prod-fracp21p2-1-frac52-without-using-properti).

Comment: The number $p^2+1$, where $p$ is an odd prime, is never prime. So it is obvious that there aren't infinite many primes of the form $p^2+1$, $p$ prime, in fact there is only one such prime, namely $5$.

Comment: We do not even need these manipulations. If $p$ is an odd prime, it is ovbious that $p^2+1$ is even, and since it is greater than $2$, it cannot be prime.

Comment: Fascinating that there doesn't seem to be an elementary proof. If we consider proving this by cancellation, the denominator is a multiple of 3 but the numerator isn't! I don't know what to make of that.

Comment: A consequence of this is that the OP identity is equal to $3/2$ when only odd primes are considered, another neat result!

Answer (score 13):

From [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164092/computing-prod-p-fracp2-1p21-without-the-zeta-function):   $$\frac{2}{5}=\frac{36}{90}=\frac{6^2}{90}=\frac{\zeta(4)}{\zeta(2)^2}=\prod_p\frac{(1-\frac{1}{p^2})^2}{(1-\frac{1}{p^4})}=\prod_p \left(\frac{(p^2-1)^2}{(p^2+1)(p^2-1)}\right)=\prod_p\left(\frac{p^2-1}{p^2+1}\right)$$

$$\implies \prod_p \left(\frac{p^2-1}{p^2+1}\right)=\frac{2}{5}$$

Comment: Wow, very elegant indeed.

Comment: I am a little bit new to this, is $\zeta$ the riemann zeta function or which?

Comment: @mathreadler Yes $\zeta (k) = \sum \frac{1}{n^k}$